# I have a Magic keyboard with the numeric keypad, how do i use it in bootcamp with windows 10?

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

I got a wireless magic keyboard with the numeric keypad. I installed bootcamp using windows 10 and am unable to connect the keyboard. At this point all i can do is use it plugged in. How do i pair it over bluetooth to be used wirelessly.

When adding a bluetooth device in windows 10, i can see the keyboard paired, pressing a key changes the text to 'Connected' and then back to paired. This happens with every keystroke rendering it unusable. How do i fix this?

Comment: anyone has any idea on this?

Comment: Anyone? I really need to get this working.

Answer (score -1):

I'm writing this with my new Magic Keyboard on my Windows 10 (64 bit) PC. I connected with a Logitech 'Dual Mode' Bluetooth V4/BLE dongle, which I installed first. Note I do not have bootcamp (I don't even know what that is/for)

There are a few differences to a normal windows keyboard:
- ALT key renamed 'option' 
- I have have to use the 'command' key for the Windows key 
- BACKSPACE is named Delete (there's a separate forward Delete key too)

Apart from these it seems completely normal so far, supporting all other keystrokes like F2, Control-Home, Conttrol-ALT-Delete (i.e. Control-option-Delete)

The only niggle = I can't tell the current charge level of the rechargeable battery. But even if the battery gets too low I can just plug in the USB-Lightning charge cable provided, and keep typing while it's charging.

All these minor shortcomings are well and truly outweighed by the appearance and feel of the beautfully styled keyboard

Hope this helps ...

Comment: Bootcamp is a specific Apple-provided way to run WIndows on a Mac.  That you are successfully using the keyboard on a PC really isn't very relevant to the problems raised in the question.